# Error from anonymous function: unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple .map() method that should return a list of `<li>` elements inside a `<ul>` but I am getting a syntax error of "unexpected token <"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tired everything.  Searched as well.  My editor doesn't show any syntax issues.  Says it is on the return line of the .map()

```
const servicesArray = languages.en.servicesListLi;
$('#servicesListUl').append(servicesArray.map((item, i) => {
<li key={i}>{item}</li>;})
);
```

Expecting a return of 5 `<li>` elements.

Comment: Please confirm if this is React / JSX code?

Comment: Put the returning value in parenthesis

Comment: Straight JS.  I realise I forgot JSX 101 knowledge.  Back ticks.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

- wrap your HTML with grave accents to be a valid [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- change the references to `${i}` and `${item}`
- `return` the string inside `map`; this can be omitted if you also omit the braces, e.g.:

  ```
  (item, i) => `<li key="${i}">${item}</li>`
  ```

```js
const servicesArray = ["English", "Spnish"];
$('#servicesListUl').append(servicesArray.map((item, i) => {
  return `<li key="${i}">${item}</li>`;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="servicesListUl"></ul>
```

Comment: BACKTICKS! How could I forget.  Working now.  Thank you!